# Angular 2 button widget inside function all page load variable gets undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I create a common widgets for button element.

Widget - TS:

```
import { Component, Input, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './app-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-button.component.less']
})

export class AppButtonComponent {
//parameter

@Input() public callback : Function;

}
```

Widget - html:

```
<button (click)="callback()" type="button">TestButton</button>
```

Another component, where i use above button component:

HTML:

```
<app-button [callback]="clickEvent"></app-button>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ContentChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId:"appComponent",
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})

export class AppComponent {
user={
    name:"test",
    placeholder:"plac"
  }
userString='';
   public clickEvent(){
        this.userString = JSON.stringify(this.user);
        console.info('obj = '+ this.userString);
      }
}
```

I get below console message after clicking on button:

```
obj = undefined
```

If I missed something that's why i didn't get page load variable into button callback function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For emitting custom events from directives and components its advisable to use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)

So make below changes an check it again :

// Widget

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './app-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-button.component.less']
})

export class AppButtonComponent {
  //parameter

  @EventEmitter() public callback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public onClick(e) {
    this.callback.emit(e);
  }

}
```

// Widget HTML

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)" type="button">TestButton</button>
```

// Usage

```
<app-button (callback)="clickEvent($event)"></app-button>
```

//Compoenent

```
export class AppComponent {
  public userString:string = '';
  public user: any = {
    name:"test",
    placeholder:"plac"
  };

  public clickEvent(){
    this.userString = JSON.stringify(this.user);
    console.info('obj = '+ this.userString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal. I didn't get undefined error in console. But this method fire on page load.
//widget TS
@Output() public callback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

//component HTML
<app-button [callback]="clickEvent()"></app-button>

if i pass argument into clickEvent method as "$event" i get console error.

I use wrong eventemitter?

Comment: to use `EventEmitter` we have to bind event with `<app-button (callback)="clickEvent()"></app-button>` not `<app-button [callback]="clickEvent()"></app-button>`

Comment: To know about event-binding check more at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

Comment: Thanks Krunal :)
issue was from my side. i did possible changes into my application and your solution work for me...!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a regular function as a callback.
When it is called in the `AppButtonComponent` the `this` refers to your function object and not to `AppComponent`.

Send an arrow function instead which takes the scope of the object in which it is defined and not where it is called.

```
 clickEvent=()=>{
        this.userString = JSON.stringify(this.user);
        console.info('obj = '+ this.userString);
      }
```